What is this accussative doing with a passive verb?
In the Pseudo-Ovidian Metamorphosis Flaminis in Gallo, we find this hexameter:

Induitur plūmās simul et vittāta sacerdōs.
And at the same time, the fillet-wearing priestess was wrapped(?) in feathers.

(Following the general theme of the Metamorphoses, this passage describes a flamen and a Vestal transformed into chickens. The flamen's transformation just finished, now the Vestal's is beginning.)
But what is plūmās doing here? It looks like an accusative object of induitur, but that's a passive verb, which should not be able to take a direct object. And since she's still mostly human at this point, it doesn't seem like an accusative of respect—she's not being "clothed with respect to her feathers", since she's just gaining them now, she doesn't have any yet.
I know that Greek has the "retained accusative", where a passive verb can keep the accusative object it had when it was active. I've never seen that before in Latin, though. While this text is mediaeval, it's trying to imitate Ovid's style, so I imagine this is meant to be some kind of Classical construction.
I've asked before about passive verbs with accusative objects; have I finally come across one in the wild?

More pressing question: What's the ablative in the title doing?

@SebastianKoppehel Honestly, that one's easier to understand to me; messing up one word in a title like that could easily happen while copying a text, but induitur is in a line of hexameter where induit couldn't possibly fit.

Well, plumis instead of plumas would fit, but anyway... I have no idea about the accusative.

What's the date of composition? Perhaps late usage? DMLBS, induere, 6 records some similar-looking situations: [fideles] abicientes opera tenebrarum ~untur arma lucis [cf. Rom. xiii 12] Bede Cant. 1116; ne ‥ ~amini ‥ diabolicam feritatem Gros. Ep. 48 p. 143 (v. exossator).

@Kingshorsey Definitely mediaeval, given the contents.

This is not a full answer, but merely two points that might shed some light on the issue.
Passivization with two objects
My first guess was that induere was being used with two objects like docere; then it would make sense to passivize it in only one of the objects.
That would naturally leave you with a passive verb and an accusative object.
The best fit in the Lewis & Short entry for induo is under I. Lit.:

“et eamst (sc. vestem) indutus?” Ter. Eun. 4, 4, 40

Looking up act 4, scene 4 gives instead:

Et ea est indutus?

This hints at there being different editions, some with ablative and some with accusative.
Perhaps the original was accusative and the ablative is a later correction.
Looking into different Latin editions of Eunuchus might shed some light on the matter.
The accusative in L&S is unlikely to be a mere misprint, as eam and vestem are in the same case.
Mixed usages
Looking at the L&S entry, we see induere used in two major ways:

person in dative, clothing in accusative
person in accusative, clothing in ablative

Mixing up these two well attested constructions and ending up with two accusatives sounds like a very reasonable mistake — if it is indeed a mistake at all.

While investigating, I came across this answer from brianpck that was exactly what I was looking for!
While the text is mediaeval, this is actually good Classical style. For example, Vergil does the same:

lōrīcam induitur fīdōque accingitur ēnse
he puts on his mail and girds on his trusty sword

This construction is only found with a few verbs, all of which specifically involve putting on or taking off clothes, and it's usually lumped in with the "Greek accusative" (accusative of specification, accusative of body parts). But etymologically, this is a native Latin construction, not one borrowed from Greek. It was the standard way of using verbs like induere on yourself in Plautus and Ennius, and it's only later that the active forms of these verbs became so dominant.
Some grammarians call this a special use of the passive voice; others say that there's an active induō and a deponent induor side by side. But the result is the same either way: it's a fossil of the Proto-Indo-European middle voice, with passive forms used whenever the person clothing and the person being clothed are the same, and an accusative direct object of the clothes being worn.
In this case, this means the proper translation would be something like "she wraps herself in feathers", as if it were a Greek middle-voice verb.
